# How to run old school Java programs with latest Java LTS 11?

Tags: java, java-11, java-6, java-5

I want to run Siemens LOGO Soft Comfort.

```
dell@dell-Precision-M6400:~/Hämtningar/Logo 6.1/Linux/tools/Application$ ./LOGOComfort 
Unrecognized option: -Xincgc
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
dell@dell-Precision-M6400:~/Hämtningar/Logo 6.1/Linux/tools/Application$
```

This is Siemens LOGO soft comfort 6.1 and I have a license for that. But I have an issue.

```
Unrecognized option: -Xincgc
```

So how can I do so latest Java LTS 11 can work with Java from 2008? I assume that is Java SE 6 or J2SE 5.0.

With LOGO software, it comes with two folders **bin** and **lib**

[image]

[image]

**Update:**

I removed the `-Xincgc`  in `LOGOComfort.lax` file and now I got this

```
dell@dell-Precision-M6400:~/Hämtningar/Logo 6.1/Linux/tools/Application$ ./LOGOComfort 
Invocation of this Java Application has caused an InvocationTargetException. This application will now exit. (LAX)

Stack Trace:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/java/swing/plaf/windows/WindowsLookAndFeel
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:698)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:621)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:579)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    at DE.siemens.ad.logo.app.Application.<clinit>(Application.java:141)
    at Start.startApplication(Start.java:570)
    at Start.main(Start.java:553)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at com.zerog.lax.LAX.launch(DashoA8113)
    at com.zerog.lax.LAX.main(DashoA8113)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 18 more
This Application has Unexpectedly Quit: Invocation of this Java Application has caused an InvocationTargetException. This application will now exit. (LAX)
dell@dell-Precision-M6400:~/Hämtningar/Logo 6.1/Linux/tools/Application$
```

**Update:**

Solution:

1. Remove -Xincgc
2. Use Java 8 instead. It requries Swing. Java 11 does not use Swing

Comment: Why you don't install an old java version? You can easily have many java versions on the same physical machine.

Comment: `LOGOComfort` is likely a shell script, so edit the script and remove the offending option.

Comment: As there is a folder named "Applet" - if you want to run applets, you will need an ancient browser version or a dedicated applet-viewer (such as the one that came with old versions of the JDK)

Comment: @Andreas "Xincgc" did not exist in  `LOGOComfort`

Comment: Is there a way to search for `-Xincgc` in linux shell terminal?

Comment: Yes, and you'd know that if you did a web search: [`search for text in files in linux shell terminal`](https://www.google.com/search?q=search+for+text+in+files+in+linux+shell+terminal)

Comment: @Andreas I found `-Xincgc` now in `LOGOComfort.lax` file. I removed it and got this as above.

Comment: Wonder why code running on Linux is trying to use a Windows-only class like `WindowsLookAndFeel`. Seems you need to install an older version of Java, i.e. a version that the Logo is compatible with. Or upgrade to a newer Logo version.

Comment: @Andreas You're rigth. I will think that I will install Java 6. But do I need to remove Java 11 then?

Comment: @DanielMårtensson no need to remove the newer version - Java versions can coexist just fine. You'll have to specify the path to the one you want to use explicitly, however.

Comment: Thank you the incredible @Hulk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

open the file 'LOGOComfort', as it is likely a shell script. Find the `-Xincgc` option and remove it.

If it's gobbledygook, install a java6, which does have the now removed `-Xincgc` option.

If that's not an option, make a fake java: Make a script that rests at the 'real' java location, and all it does is scan for all command line args, strip -Xincgc from it, and pass the rest through unmolested to the real java. This is a crazy hack and is likely to break other things, but it will probably 'fix' this. I strongly recommend you go with one of the first 2 options first.

There is no way to tell java 11+: Can you 'support' the -Xincgc option.

Answer (score 2):

The error message is saying that it can't find the look and feel profile associated with Windows.

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/java/swing/plaf/windows/WindowsLookAndFeel

Clearly, this app was intended for Windows in the past. Maybe the script changes the look and feel profile, but I couldn't tell you without looking at it.

Best bet is try this on a Windows machine and see if it goes any further. If not then you'll have to try it with an older JRE that supports that, such as JRE 6.

Comment: Can I install Java 6 without removing Java 11?

Comment: I want to use Java 11 as default

Comment: Yes, as mentioned above, you can have multiple instances of Java installed on the same computer.

Comment: OK. Now I have Java 6 at `/usr/lib/jvm`

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a old question, but I still have a solution that may work (it worked for me). You need to make the application java executable by

```
chmod a+x $PATH_TO_LOGO/Application_64/jre/bin/java
```